# Mirror material works in blender but does not work in standalone game?

Tags: python, game-engine, materials

I have made a game with mirror material using the Render To Texture script. When I hit <kbd>P</kbd> in Blender, it works. But when I *Saved as Runtime Game* and opened my runtime game file, the mirror material was black and did not work.

Why it doesn't work and how to make it work?

The result when I export game to Runtime:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/Blender/2.72/scripts/addons/io_export_pc2.py", line 156, in poll
    return context.active_object.type in {'MESH', 'CURVE', 'SURFACE', 'FONT'}
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'type'

location: <unknown location>:-1
```

The code I use for mirror relfection:

```
######################################################
#
#    RenderToTexture.py        Blender 2.50
#
#    Tutorial for using RenderToTexture.py can be found at
#
#    www.tutorialsforblender3d.com
#
#    Released under the Creative Commons Attribution 3.0 Unported License.  
#
#    If you use this code, please include this information header.
#
######################################################

#import GameLogic
import GameLogic

# get current scene
scene = GameLogic.getCurrentScene()

# get the current controller
controller = GameLogic.getCurrentController()

# get object script is attached to
obj = controller.owner

# check to see RenderToTexture has been added
if "RenderToTexture" in obj:

    # update the texture
    obj["RenderToTexture"].refresh(True)

# if RenderToTexture hasn't been added 
else:

    # import VideoTexture module
    import VideoTexture

    # get a list of objects in the scene
    objList = scene.objects

    # get camera name being used for render to texture
    camName = obj['cam']

    # get camera object
    cam = objList[camName]

    # get the texture material ID
    matID = VideoTexture.materialID(obj, "MA" + obj['material'])

    # set the texture
    renderToTexture = VideoTexture.Texture(obj, matID)

    # get the texture image
    renderToTexture.source = VideoTexture.ImageRender(scene,cam)

    # save RenderToTexture as an object variable
    obj["RenderToTexture"] = renderToTexture
```

Comment: What modifiers? I don't use modifiers. It is not Mirror modifier, but a reflection texture(python script, that Always gets render from camera and makes that render into texture)

Comment: If that the case, enabling True-Level-triggering should fix.

Comment: I have enabled true level triggering.

Comment: @AdriansNetlis Better to edit your question and put the code there. Comments don't allow newlines and are limited to 500 chars.

Comment: Did as you said...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason the obj["RenderToTexture"].refresh(True) makes it not work. If I change it to obj["RenderToTexture"].refresh(False) it works also in standalone for me. Strange...